# Не отправляет форму в модальном окне. Почему?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, form

Ещё раз задаюсь вопросом с большими подробностями. 
Был самописный сайт, потом натянули на WP. Перестали работать формы. Как я выяснил, просто потерялся обработчик php. Прикрутил обработчик. Формы на сайте заработали, кроме форм которые в модальных окнах. 
Окна прописаны в вёрстке в основном шаблоне, появляются навешеванием активного класса. Обработчик JS располагается в футере.

Код обработчика:

```
    $(document).on("submit", "form", function () {
    // Получение ID формы
    var formID = $(this).attr('id');
    // Добавление решётки к имени ID
    var formNm = $('#' + formID);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'mail.php',
        data: formNm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {

            $(formNm).html(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
            // Вывод текста ошибки отправки
            $(formNm).html(error);         
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Сама форма (у форм id разный):

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST" id="formModal1">
                    <input type="text" name="t-number" placeholder="Ваш телефон" required />
                    <input type="submit" placeholder="Получить консультацию" />
                </form>
```

php обработчик:

```
 <?php
  if (isset($_POST['t-numder'])) {$phone = $_POST['t-number'];}
  if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email'];}


/* Сюда впишите свою эл. почту */
 $address = "";

/* А здесь прописывается текст сообщения, \n - перенос строки */
 $mes = "Тема: Заказ обратного звонка!\nТелефон: $phone\nE-mail: $email";

/* А эта функция как раз занимается отправкой письма на указанный вами email */
$sub='Заказ'; //тема
$mail='Заказ <Центр юридической помощи>'; // от кого
$send = mail ($address,$sub,$mes,"Content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8\r\nFrom:$mail");

ini_set('short_open_tag', 'On');

?>
```

Подскажите куда копать? Может дело в особенностях WP каких?

Comment: Что в коде формы? Покажите его. Какие ошибки на сайте? Не работает - это ни о чем.

Comment: Можно и так делать ajax в wp, но почитайте о том, как правильно: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Comment: Думаю вопрос быстро решится если посмотреть что пишет консоль и какие ответы вовзращаются

Comment: Консоль ничего не пишет. Просто кнопка не реагирует никак.

Comment: У вас есть файл `mail.php` к которому стучится скрипт ?

Comment: Php обработчик добавил в вопрос.

Comment: То ли я ослеп, то ли устал, но в упор не вижу в форме отправки, ни phone, ни email...

Comment: А вы внимательный). На самом деле обработчик поправил, извините. В формах которые работают два инпута, в формах которые не работают только телефон.